# How to run sonar analysis even if build failed on Jenkins

Tags: hudson, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins job to build my project run tests and then run sonar with sonar jenkins-plugin.
but when tests failed sonar analysis skipped.

Comment: Are you using Ant or Maven to run your Jenkins build ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trigger Sonar Analysis as a build step and not a post-build step. Take a look at [this](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+SonarQube+on+Jenkins+Job).
But my question is, why you should want to run a quality analysis for a project failing its build?

Comment: Yeah. I make it yesterday) no, I run code quality for My tests. but solution building and tests running and sonar in one jenkins job. So all job failed even if one test failed.

Comment: As I see it, if you use test driven developement, there are times when new tests are failing knowingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexible publish plugin in Jenkins.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin

As a post build action, use Conditional action to "Always". Whatever be the previous step result, the action would be run. Select sonar analysis as the action.

[image]